# <input type="password" ...> styling with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, input, passwords

Is this possible to change the default styling of password field? I mean replacing the default stars-symbols with something like `&bull;` or etc. jQuery or simply css/html?
Thanx.

Comment: While it may be possible, I would strongly suggest not doing this. You shouldn't do anything unexpected when dealing with people's passwords.

Answer (score 2):

The masking characters are set by the browser and operating system and you can't customize them with CSS.

Here's a [thread that covers it more](http://www.htmlforums.com/css/t-password-input-fields-103004.html). You could fake it, but it will break if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: Not if you use progressive enhancement. Start with a password field and use javascript to replace it with your custom field.