# input password field->replace bullets with images

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I need to replace the bullets in an `<input type="password">` field with any image (the same for all bullets). Can this be achieved using CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: Good question, but I believe the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

Right. I've had a noodle on JSFiddle and I've come up with http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/SzuD4/.

It's far from perfect, but it's a starting point. Basically, you need to position a `div` over the `input`. When the `div` is clicked, jQuery (sorry, but it's still JavaScript) will focus the input, making it typeable.

Comment: Not every keypress results in a new character being added to the input - or may produce more than one (e.g. backspace, CTRL-V, etc)

Comment: You are indeed correct - didn't think of that. I made the fiddle as a sort of reference version, however when I've got more time I'll improve it. There isn't an ideal solution to the OP's question, but it's _sort of_ possible.

Comment: It is far from perfect, but a very good proof of concept that @mirek can use as a jumping point.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to alter the password masking is with js but do you really want to rely on js enabled for a password field? Probably not...

Similar thread here: [<input type="password" ...> styling with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343662/input-type-password-styling-with-jquery)